# Add a new line in message body using the following vbscript

Tags: email, vbscript

I have created a txt file to support the message body of the vbscript but it only reads the last line of the messagebody.txt

```
    WScript.Sleep 100

    Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set objOutlook=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Set objMail=objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")


Set objFileToReadTo          = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDesktop + "\\send email with attachment\List_To.txt",1)
Set objFileToReadCC          = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDesktop + "\\send email with attachment\List_CC.txt",1)
Set objFileToReadSubject     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDesktop + "\\send email with attachment\List_Subject.txt",1)
Set objFileToReadBody        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDesktop + "\\send email with attachment\Email Body.txt",1)
Set objFileToReadAttachments = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDesktop + "\\send email with attachment\List_Attachments_withFileExtension.txt",1)

Dim strLineTo
Dim strLineCC
Dim strLineSubject
Dim strLineBody
Dim strLineAttachments

objMail.Display

WScript.Sleep 10

do while not objFileToReadTo.AtEndOfStream
strLineTo = objFileToReadTo.ReadLine()
objMail.To=strLineTo
loop
objFileToReadTo.Close 

WScript.Sleep 10
do while not objFileToReadCC.AtEndOfStream
strLineCC = objFileToReadCC.ReadLine()
objMail.cc = strLineCC
loop
objFileToReadCC.Close 
'41
WScript.Sleep 10
do while not objFileToReadSubject.AtEndOfStream
strLineSubject = objFileToReadSubject.ReadLine()
objMail.Subject = strLineSubject
loop
objFileToReadSubject.Close 
'48
WScript.Sleep 10
do while not objFileToReadBody.AtEndOfStream
strLineBody = objFileToReadBody.ReadLine()
objMail.Body = strLineBody & vbCRLF  
loop
objFileToReadBody.Close 
'55
WScript.Sleep 10
do while not objFileToReadAttachments.AtEndOfStream
strLineAttachments = objFileToReadAttachments.ReadLine()
objMail.Attachments.Add(strLineAttachments)
loop
objFileToReadAttachments.Close 
'62

'objShell.Sendkeys "%s"
WScript.Sleep 40
'objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
'objShell.SendKeys "{UP}"
'objShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
'set MyEmail=nothing
'objOutlook.Quit
'Set objMail = Nothing
'Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

and here is my messagebody.txt

```
Hi,

Testing vbscript

Regards,

abcd
```

It only reads the last ABCD and displays the same on the oulook window.

How do I make the scipt understand multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why you have used different text files for storing ToList, CCList, body etc. but if you are sure about using this approach, I won't change it.

I am just pointing out why you are not getting the full text in the email body. Replace the following code:

```
do while not objFileToReadBody.AtEndOfStream
    strLineBody = objFileToReadBody.ReadLine()            'Here you are just overwriting the value contained in strLineBody in each loop iteration. Hence, in the end, only last line is left in this variable
    objMail.Body = strLineBody & vbCRLF  
loop
```

WITH

```
objMail.Body = objFileToReadBody.readAll
```

Comment: Actually the reason is they don’t append the text to the Body each line replaces the body text, instead of `ReadAll` this would fix the issue `objMail.Body = objMail.Body & strLineBody`.

Comment: @Lankymart what else have I written in the comment part of the code. I have just written that with each readline call, he is overwriting the existing line. So, a better way to include all the contents is to use readAll method at once and store it in email body. What's wrong with that?

Comment: No a better way is to append each line, using `ReadAll` is inefficient especially as the text requirement increases in size... and it will.

Comment: Apologies, the comments are not obvious when viewing the thread via mobile *([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scUqA.jpg))*.

Comment: @Lankymart Not an issue man. I did some research about your comment regarding readline vs readAll and found that you were right. Thanks for teaching me a new thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you replace the `Body` with each line you read, when you should be appending to it. Switch this line;

```
objMail.Body = strLineBody & vbCRLF
```

to be;

```
objMail.Body = objMail.Body & strLineBody & vbNewLine
```

If you forgo the loop and use `ReadAll` *(as [@Gurman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5331061/gurman) has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47853438/692942))*, bear in mind that while this will be fine for minimal text, larger text files will make the process less efficient then looping through each line as you have started to do already.